# How to write a PHP Regex to match string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I only knows basic regex, so I am look for help here.

I need to match URL with this pattern:

`/kb/This-is-possible-title-12345.html`

The URL will always ends with -nnnnn.html. Currently I have this regex pattern:

`'kb/[a-zA-Z_-]*(\d+)\.html'`

however, this does not work if the portion contains numbers, such as

`/kb/This-is-12345-possible-title-12345.html`

This needs to be done with PHP preg_match function.

Comment: I think we'd need to know more about the constraints before being able to answer. Can you have "/kb/This8-is-1234-possible-5title-1234.html" or does any section with numbers have to be only numbers?

Comment: Is the URL all by itself, or is it a part of a larger text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me: `/kb/[\w_-]*-(\d+)\.html$`.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance what you have looks right but you need to escape the forward slash so change '/' to '\/'.

Comment: depends what delimiter he's using.

Answer (score 0):

`'/kb/[^/]*-\d{5}\.html'`

This matches "/kb/" "any characters except '/'" "hyphen" "5 digits" ".html"